# empty row in listview

Tags: android, listview

I created a listView which I associated with a adapter. Problem is that rows appear empty even if I set the textview from the view which was created. I mention that the number of rows from listview is right. Thank you.

shopping_page_item

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter

```
    public class ShoppingListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    public ShoppingListAdapter(Context context, String content[]) {
        super(context, R.layout.shopping_page_item, content);

    }



        @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shopping_page_item, parent, false);

        }

        TextView editText =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.productTitle);
        editText.setText(getItem(position).toString());


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which adapter are you used for the list `getItemCount()`  it's not there?

Comment: share  all content of ShoppingListAdapter.

Comment: I updated the post. This is the adapter after i have deleted as much I could just to discover what is not working. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/productTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: @TomaRadu Happy to help you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent layout's height is match_content, make it wrap_content. It may be possible that your one row covering the complete screen.

Comment: When content has X strings on the screen appears X rows (separated by line) but they are empy.

Comment: you need to set textColor of your textview in xml. It will work start working.